# Hay una manera para que una aplicación de escritorio le niegue la entrada al mouse?

Tags: python-3.x

Actualmente lo estoy intentando con tkinter, **solo he conseguido que el programa siempre este adelante de los demás, pero no he conseguido que al momento de hacer click en el programa el mouse pase de el y haga click en el escritorio. Cualquier sugerencia la voy a valorar mucho, muchas gracias.**

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.configure(bg="blue")
root.attributes("-topmost", 1)
root.attributes("transparentcolor","red")
root.geometry("1000x300+200+300")

frame = Frame(root, bg='#633763')
frame.pack()

label = Label(frame, text='Cuadricula', height=900, width=900, bg="red", border=0)
label.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: En la parte transparente me funciona perfectamente. Hago clic en la parte transparente y hace clic debajo de la ventana. Esto no funciona si hago clic en el texto cuadricula. Buscas que funcione con eso?

Comment: la base de las ventanas "es hacer específicamente eso, que el foco de interacción sea la ventana" para lo que quieres creo que debes hacer una mescla con la libreria [pyautogui](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io) o [mouse](https://www.thepythoncode.com/article/control-mouse-python) creo yo

Comment: @DanteS.Es exactamente lo que busco, es como poner una marca de agua en mi monitor o una cuadrícula que se vea pero no se le pueda hacer click. Con respecto a pyautogui, lo pensé pero es la manera adecuada de hacer esto, no lo sé. Gracias por comentar.

Comment: `root.overrideredirect(1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A mi no me convence mucho (pues no se ve bien), pero la mejor forma que se me ocurre es minimizar la ventana, hacer clic con algún modulo y restaurar la ventana.

Código de ejemplo (en este caso uso pynput)

```
from tkinter import *
from pynput.mouse import Controller, Button
import time

root = Tk()
root.configure(bg="blue")
root.attributes("-topmost", 1)
root.attributes("-transparentcolor","red")
root.geometry("1000x300+200+300")

mouse = Controller()

def click_debajo(event):
    button = (Button.left, None, Button.right)[event.num - 1]

    if(button is not None):
        # minimizamos la ventana
        root.iconify()
        # actualizamos para que se minimize
        root.update()

        # esperamos 0.2 segundos
        time.sleep(0.2)

        # Hacemos click
        mouse.click(button)

        # restauramos la ventana
        root.deiconify()

frame = Frame(root, bg='#633763')
frame.pack()

label = Label(frame, text='Cuadricula', height=900, width=900, bg="red", border=0)
label.pack()

# Enlazo el evento que se ejecuta cuando se hace clic en el label (proveniente de cualquier botón del mouse) con una función.
label.bind("<Button>", click_debajo)

root.mainloop()
```

Te recomiendo considerar la posibilidad de que recurrir a un modulo que no sea de GUI (quizá pywin32 o jugar un poco con funciones de C con ctypes sirva para poner una marca de agua, pero no estoy seguro, no se nada de esa area). Incluso quizá crear tu propio sistema operativo o recurrir a otro.